# Blinking while drawing on canvas in loop

Tags: android, canvas

I have problem with drawing on android. I'm trying to create simple game that includes robots which will paint screen on different colors. Firstly I'm trying only paint screen without any robot image (I'm planing place it later on higher transparent view) but I encountered problem with flashing canvas.

So this is my render method. I can't use every time `canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);` before drawing because as I said robots need to paint screen with own color (Red and Blue). Other idea was to store every robot location and paint it on every "render" method, but it takes too much time and after few secounds game becoming really slow.

```
public void render(Canvas canvas) {

    if(lastD1X!=-1 && lastD1Y!=-1){
        canvas.drawLine(lastD1X, lastD1Y, droid.getX(), droid.getY(), drawPaint);
    } 
    lastD1X = droid.getX();
    lastD1Y = droid.getY();

    if(lastD2X!=-1 && lastD2Y!=-1){
        canvas.drawLine(lastD2X, lastD2Y, droid2.getX(), droid2.getY(), drawPaint2);
    } 
    lastD2X = droid2.getX();
    lastD2Y = droid2.getY();
}
```

This is my game loop:

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        Canvas canvas;
        Log.d(TAG, "Starting game loop");
    long beginTime;     // the time when the cycle begun
    long timeDiff;      // the time it took for the cycle to execute
    int sleepTime;      // ms to sleep (<0 if we're behind)
    int framesSkipped;  // number of frames being skipped 

    sleepTime = 0;

    while (running) {
        canvas = null;
        // try locking the canvas for exclusive pixel editing
        // in the surface
        try {
            canvas = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
            synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                beginTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                framesSkipped = 0;  // resetting the frames skipped
                // update game state 
                this.gamePanel.update();
                // render state to the screen
                // draws the canvas on the panel
                this.gamePanel.render(canvas);              
                // calculate how long did the cycle take
                timeDiff = System.currentTimeMillis() - beginTime;
                // calculate sleep time
                sleepTime = (int)(FRAME_PERIOD - timeDiff);

                if (sleepTime > 0) {
                    // if sleepTime > 0 we're OK
                    try {
                        // send the thread to sleep for a short period
                        // very useful for battery saving
                        Thread.sleep(sleepTime);    
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                }

                while (sleepTime < 0 && framesSkipped < MAX_FRAME_SKIPS) {
                    // we need to catch up
                    this.gamePanel.update(); // update without rendering
                    sleepTime += FRAME_PERIOD;  // add frame period to check if in next frame
                    framesSkipped++;
                }
            }
        } finally {
            // in case of an exception the surface is not left in 
            // an inconsistent state
            if (canvas != null) {
                surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }   // end finally
    }
}
```